# Trying to understand adadelta algorithm

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement adadelta to my simple feed forward neural network
but I think I'm having some troubles understanding the article.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701v1.pdf
It is a small article explaining/introducing adadelta algorithm.
Only 1 and a half pages are focused on formulas.

Starting from part:

> Algorithm 1 Computing ADADELTA update at time t

---

**Question 1**
part: *'3: Compute Gradient: gt'*

How exactly do I calculate gradient here?
Is my way correct:

```
/* calculating gradient value for neuron what is inside the hidden layer
gradient = sum of ( outcoming connection target's gradient * outcoming connection's weight ) * derivative function */
double CalculatHiddenGradient() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < OutcomingConnections.size(); i++) {
        sum += OutcomingConnections[i]->weight * OutcomingConnections[i]->target->gradient;
    }
    return (1.0 - output * output) * sum; // tanh's derivative function
}

// calculating gradient value for output neurons where we know the desired output value
double CalculatGradient(double TargetOutput) {
    return (TargetOutput - output) * (1.0 - output * output);
}
```

---

**Question 2** part: *'5: Compute Update: ∆xt'*

formula (14)
says following:

> ∆xt = -( RMS[∆x]t−1) / RMS[g]t) * gt;

is the RMS[∆x]t−1 calculating as followings:

> RMS[∆x]t−1 = sqrt( E[∆x²]t-1 + e )

taking the body from formula (9)?

---

Based on what I corrently understand, I was able to write this piece of code:

```
class AdaDelta {
private:
    vector<double> Eg; // E[g²]
    vector<double> Ex; // E[∆x²]
    vector<double> g; // gradient
    int windowsize;
    double p; // Decay rate ρ
    double e; // Constant e, epsilon?

public:
    AdaDelta(int WindowSize = 32, double DecayRate = 0.95, double ConstantE = 0.001) { // initalizing variables
        Eg.reserve(WindowSize + 1);
        Ex.reserve(WindowSize + 1);

        Eg.push_back(0.0); // E[g²]t
        Ex.push_back(0.0); // E[∆x²]t
        g.push_back(0.0); // (gradient)t

        windowsize = WindowSize; // common value:?

        p = DecayRate; // common value:0.95
        e = ConstantE; // common value:0.001
    }

    // Does it return weight update value?
    double CalculateUpdated(double gradient) {
        double dx; // ∆xt
        int t;

        // for t = 1 : T do %% Loop over # of updates
        for (t = 1; t < Eg.size(); t++) {

            // Accumulate Gradient
            Eg[t] = (p * Eg[t - 1] + (1.0 - p) * (g[t] * g[t]));

            // Compute Update
            dx = -(sqrt(Ex[t - 1] + e) / sqrt(Eg[t] + e)) * g[t];

            // Accumulate Updates
            Ex[t] = Ex[t - 1] + (1.0 - p) * (dx * dx);
        }

        /* calculate new update
        =================================== */
        t = g.size();
        g.push_back(gradient);

        // Accumulate Gradient
        Eg.push_back((p * Eg[t - 1] + (1.0 - p) * (g[t] * g[t])));

        // Compute Update
        dx = -(sqrt(Ex[t - 1] + e) / sqrt(Eg[t] + e)) * g[t];

        // Accumulate Updates
        Ex.push_back(Ex[t - 1] + (1.0 - p) * (dx * dx));

        // Deleting adadelta update when window has grown bigger than we allow
        if (g.size() >= windowsize) {
            Eg[1] = 0.0;
            Ex[1] = 0.0;
            Eg.erase(Eg.begin());
            Ex.erase(Ex.begin());
            g.erase(g.begin());

        }
        return dx;
    }
};
```

---

**Question 3**
In backpropagation, updating weight goes like this

> target's gradient * source's output * learning rate

but in adadelta algorithm I don't see that action.
Should I mix the source's output with target's gradient before calling the 
CalculateUpdated() function or should I mix the output with returned value to get new weight value?

---

**Question 4**
A part what got me confused all the way

> 3.2. Idea 2: Correct Units with Hessian Approximation

I don't quite understand what formula part are we updating here or what changes.
Where do we apply the formula below?

formula (13)
∆x = (∆x/∂f)/∂x;

---

**Question 5**
what does ∆x, ∂f, ∂x stand for in formula (13)?

---

Thanks!

Comment: It will be helpful also to state the topology of your network. How many layers and how many neurons on each layer?

Comment: I will go with simple network meant to solve xor problem so later one
i could understand how to make more complicated networks.

One hidden layer, two inputs, two hidden neurons and one output.
Input and hidden layer having one bias neuron.

Comment: David Miller did the same thing so maybe you should take a look at his [**Tutorial**](https://vimeo.com/19569529)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then David Miller used some sort of momentum term to optimize gradient decent algorithm but I'm trying to understand Adadelta.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you need to know about AdaDelta is the general context of online machine learning. *Online* machine learning is where you get your data one-at-a-time (and thus have to update your model's parameters as the data comes in), as opposed to *batch* machine learning where you can generate your machine learning model with access to the entire dataset all at once.

Basically, you have a set of datapoints along with the targets you're trying to predict in the form

```
D = {(A_1,b_1), (A_2,b_2), (A_3,b_3), ...}
```

where A_k is the k-th piece of training data and b_k is the correct answer. You generally want your machine learning model (e.g. a classifier or a regressor, for example a neural network or perhaps a linear model) to update its internal parameter

```
x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)
```

as it reads in the datapoints (A_k,b_k) one at a time, i.e. you want the model to update x in "realtime" as the data comes in. This is as opposed to something like batch learning, where your model has access to the entire dataset D all at once.

Now, we generally have a notion of "cost" --- in linear regression, the cost function that we're trying to minimize is the root mean square (RMS) of the difference between the predicted target value and the actual target value.

Recalling the definition of online linear regression, you have a [*stochastic gradient descent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Iterative_method) based update step where the parameters x get updated based on all the data the model has seen so far:

```
x_new <- x_old - gradient(RMS[predicted-actual])
```

What update rules like AdaGrad and AdaDelta do is to provide a "nicer" way to perform updates --- this can mean things like making sure the parameters converge to their optimal value faster, or in the case of AdaDelta, it means that the parameters x "step closer" to their optimal values in appropriately-sized steps, with the step size changing based on past performance.

Let's go through your questions, one question at a time:

- **Question 1:**

The gradient in higher dimensions (i.e. when x is represented by an array) is defined as

```
gt = (∂f/∂x_1, ∂f/∂x_2, ..., ∂f/∂x_n) (xt)
```

where f(x1,x2,...,x_n) is the function you're trying to minimize; in most cases it's the cost function at a single example as a function of x, the model parameters. In other words: take the derivatives of the cost function and then evaluate it at the current parameters xt.

- **Question 2:**

Based on my understanding, the RMS of delta-x is defined as

```
RMS[\Delta x]_{t-1} = \sqrt{ E[\Delta x^2]_{t-1} + \epsilon },
```

where

```
E[\Delta x^2]_t = \rho E[\Delta x^2]_{t-1} + (1-\rho) g^2_T,
```

initialized with

```
E[\Delta x^2]_0 = 0.
```

- **Question 3:**

AdaDelta is purely an update rule. The general structure is something like this:

```
(new_weights @ T) := (old_weights @ T-1) - [adaptive_learning_rate] * (gradient @ T)
```

where

```
adaptive_learning_rate := -(RMS[Delta-x] @ T-1)/(RMS[gradient] @ T)
```

because the point of AdaDelta is to make the learning rate into a dynamic value rather than forcing us to choose an arbitrary value for it at the start.

- **Question 4:**

The idea behind "correcting units with Hessian approximation" comes from physical intuition, in some sense; that is to say, if you give each variable some sort of unit (length/meters, time/seconds, energy/joules, etc.) then the Hessian has the appropriate units to correct the update term so that the dimensional analysis works out.

- **Question 5:**

Delta-x is the difference in x after updating. So if x_i is your parameter before an update and x_{i+1} is your parameter after updating, then Delta-x is (x_{i+1} - x_i).

(∂f/∂x) is the derivative of the function you're trying to minimize (usually in ML, f is the cost function).